# Visual Studio Add Service Reference discovery credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, navision

When I go to add the service request I get the discovery credentials asking for my password and enter the correct username & password (With and Without Domain Name) times and then we continue on in this circle. When I go to View -> Other Windows -> Web Browser and windows security pops up.  I choose Use other account then enter for username "\matthew" to remove the domain name and then enter my regular password and that will let me into the path.  In the discovery credentials it wont allow me to enter the "\" before myusername to remove the domain.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try going to Credential Manager and see if a Windows Credentials or Web Credentials can be doing more harm than good and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are adding a Web Reference rather than a Service Reference... This used to catch me when I moved to VS 2008..

Click the Advanced Button in the bottom left, then choose 'Add web reference' in the bottom left of the 'Service Reference Settings' window. Stick in your address and go...